# Extract ith item from an array in jQuery

Tags: jquery, arrays

I need to extract the ith "age" from this array using jQuery. I'm not exactly sure how to do so, given the unique structure of my data:

```
[{"age":25},{"age":52},{"age":73},...,{"age":17}]
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Uh... `arr[i].age`? It's hardly unique, it's just an array of objects...

Comment: Uh, that doesn't work for me. I get an "undefined" error. Any idea why? Should my array variable be of a certain type? No reason to be rude bud.

Comment: @datasci it will works `var arr = [{"age":25},{"age":52},{"age":73},{"age":17}]` `alert(arr[2].age)` and dont forget array starts 0

Comment: Please create a pastebin or jsfiddle of the code, or an example with the same error. We really can't tell from the information you provided what's wrong. All we know is that something is undefined. Perhaps `arr` is null. Perhaps `i` is null. Perhaps `arr[i]` is null. Perhaps `arr[i].age` is null. Perhaps something else entirely in your code is null! On top of that, the possible reasons for each of these scenarios are themselves varied. There's just not enough information here to help :(

Comment: I can't replicate this in jsfiddle. I'm returning "age_list = simplejson.dumps(age_list)" from a django view to my template, then I'm assigning the values from {{age_list}} from my template to a variable "var age_list = $("#age_list").val();" in my script file (the values returned are structured like values in initial post). Then, I attempt to extract the ith item in this manner and it is "undefined", but when i "alert(age_list)" all values are present.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `i` is known you can just get the age as suggested by @NiettheDarkAbsol, `arr[i].age` or if you want all the ages you can iterate through the array as follows:

```
var arr = [{"age":25},{"age":52},{"age":73},...,{"age":17}];
$.each(arr, function(i,v) {
    console.log( v.age ); //gives you the age for ith element
});
```

[**WORKING JSFIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/fiddleyetu/YFbH6/)

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery, you can iterate over array values with [.each()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/)

```
$(your_array).each(function(){
    console.log(this.age);
});
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LbF5h/)

Answer (score -1):

Or cast to String and use Split command ?

Comment: This is a suggestion not an answer.